# Using getchar() to read text with no trailing newline

Tags: c, string, stack, newline, getchar

I'm working on a program with the goal of reading parentheses/brackets and figuring out if they are balanced on each side, but am running into trouble when reading the last line of text. This may be a little confusing, but I'll attach the input:

```
3          <-- The number of lines I'll scan
([])       <-- Problem
(([{}])))
([()[]()])()
```

My program works perfectly when faced with manual input; that is when I input each line myself and press enter. When I copy a block of text though, the program fails to print the final answer (yes or no) unless I press enter. This is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifndef status_h
#define status_h
enum status { SUCCESS, FAILURE };
typedef enum status Status;

enum boolean { TRUE, FALSE };
typedef enum boolean Boolean;

#endif

typedef void* NODE;

struct node {
    char data;
    struct node* next;
} *head;
typedef struct node Node;

void stack_init_default(Node* hStack);
int stack_empty(void);
char stack_top(Node* hStack);
NODE stack_pop(Node* hStack);
NODE stack_push(Node* hStack, char item);
void stack_destroy(void);

int main(int charc, char* argv[])
{
    char x;
    int num, error = 0, i;
    Node* stack;
    stack_init_default(stack);
    scanf("%d ", &num);
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        stack_destroy();
        error = 0;

    while ((x = getchar()) != '\n' )
    {
        if (x == ' ')
            continue;
        if ((x == '(')||(x == '[')||(x == '{'))
        {
            stack_push(stack, x);
        }
        else if ((x == ')')&&(stack_top(stack)=='('))
        {
            stack_pop(stack);
        }
        else if ((x == ']')&&(stack_top(stack)=='['))
        {
            stack_pop(stack);
        }
        else if ((x == '}')&&(stack_top(stack)=='{'))
        {
            stack_pop(stack);
        }
        else
        {
            error = 1;
        }
    }
            putchar('\n');
            if (stack_empty() == 0 || error == 1)
                {
                    printf("No");
                }
              else
            {
                printf("Yes");
            }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void stack_init_default(Node* hStack)
{
     head = NULL;
}

NODE stack_push(Node* hStack, char item)
{
    Node* tmp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    tmp->data = item;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}

NODE stack_pop(Node* hStack)
{
    Node* tmp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp);
    return head;
}

char stack_top(Node* hStack)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return '\0';
    }
    return head->data;
}

int stack_empty(void)
{
    return (head == NULL);
}

 void stack_destroy(void)
{

    Node* phStack = head;

    while (head != NULL)
    {
        phStack = head->next;
        free(head);
        head = phStack;
    }
    free(phStack);
    head = NULL;

}
```

My issue looks like this:

```
3
([])
(([{}])))
([()[]()])()
Yes
No

Yes
```

So my program outputs yes or no, but freezes on the last problem, waiting for me to press newline to finish the loop. I assume that the issue lies somewhere with the while loop, and that because the pasted text doesn't have a final newline the loop never ends, but I'm unsure how to fix this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the carriage return after the last input line?  Also, this isn't your immediate problem, but whenever you have a `while (getchar() != 'x')` loop - for any value of x - you need to be checking for `EOF` as well.

Comment: @zwol As far as I know, there isn't one... and as for EOF yes I'm aware, but I don't think it helps this particular program, although I probably should include it anyway. The issue I have is that I'm being given string by a website checker, and it doesn't seem to have a trailing newline. When I submitted the problem I was given the feedback that my balancing code was correct, but the output had a "presentation error", which I assume is referencing the fact that you need to manually press enter for the final answer.

Comment: @auriskv-- one reason that you should always check for `EOF` is that `getchar()` returns `EOF` in the event of an error, and you want to avoid an infinite loop in such a case.

Comment: In order to help you any further I would need to see the entire program and I would need to have access to this "website checker". Is this homework? If so, you should talk to your instructor.

Comment: @zwol It's an online judge run by University of Valladolid. The website is essentially thousands of problems, which are checked by the automated "judge" when you submit them. As for speaking to the instructor, I'm actually on school vacation, so not really possible right now. I've edited the post to include the whole program, although it is quite lengthy.

Comment: @auriskv If the program is being evaluated by an automatic process, then I bet you a cookie adding proper EOF handling will fix the problem.

Comment: @DavidBowling How would I properly check for EOF in this case? I tried using while (((x = getchar()) != '\n') && ((x = getchar()) != EOF))  as well as using the logical or operator || but I didn't get any output back.

Comment: The usual idiom is: `int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}`. You don't want to call `getchar()` twice, as you have in your example in the comments.

Comment: @DavidBowling So why would I use an integer in place of a char for the output value? Obviously it would read a char either way, but I currently use the char that I scan by pushing it onto the stack.

Comment: @zwol Alright I'll try and figure that out I guess. What do you mean by cookie in the context of this program? I'm not super familiar with the usage of that term outside of the context of websites and the internet..

Comment: A `char` may not be able to hold `EOF`, but an `int` can.

Comment: @auriskv "I bet you a cookie" is a fixed phrase in English. It refers to the kind of cookies that you eat.

Comment: @DavidBowling In fact, `EOF` is _required_ not to be representable by `char`.

Comment: @zwol Oh my lord I am so out of it, I didn't even realize you were using that expression, and I'm American...

Comment: @zwol-- I thought that a `signed char` could hold `EOF`, but `getchar()` can only return `unsigned char` or `EOF`. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @DavidBowling Technically you're right: the requirements are that `fgetc` returns either `EOF` or a value representable by `unsigned char`, and that `EOF` has type `int` and a negative value (_not_ representable by `unsigned char`). (All the other get-character functions/macros are defined to behave as-if a particular invocation of `fgetc`.) The usual value is −1, which _is_ representable by `signed char`. Still, you can't put the value returned by `getchar` into _either_ a signed or unsigned `char` without a collision between `EOF` and _some_ value that could legitimately appear in the file.

Comment: @auriskv I apologize, I assumed from your mention of the University of Valladolid that you were Spanish.